# Regarding route defining in express framework of node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am setting up the route in my app.js file. And I am passing a route for the listing of flights in the routes/flights.js file. But the problem I am facing when I am defining the route at the bottom of all route I am getting 404 error but I pass same route definition at top of all route then it is working. Please help me with this code are given below of both files. Thanks in advance.

app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var flightRouter = require('./routes/flight');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.set('X-Powered-By', 'Flight Tracker');
  next();
});
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/flight', flightRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

routes/flight.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var flights = require('../modules/data');
var flight = require('../modules/flight');

for (var number in flights) {
    flights[number] = flight(flights[number]);
}

router.get('/list', function (req, res, next) {
    // console.log('in list');
    res.render('flight', {
        title: 'All flights',
        flights: flights
    });
});

router.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    var number = req.params.id;
    if (typeof flights[number] === 'undefined') {
        res.status(404).json({
            status: 'error'
        });
    } else {
        res.json(flights[number].getInformation());
    }
});

router.put('/:id/arrived', function (req, res, next) {
    var number = req.params.id;
    if (typeof flights[number] === 'undefined') {
        res.status(404).json({
            status: 'error'
        });
    } else {
        flights[number].triggerArrive();
        res.json({
            status: 'Done'
        });
    }
});


module.exports = router;
```

```
router.get('/list', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('flight', {
        title: 'All flights',
        flights: flights
    });
});
```

this above line of code needs to work at bottom of other routes in routes/flight.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean inside the flights.js file....
This may be happening because the /:id also captures the /list route since :id doesn't have any constraints thats why it must be defined before /:id
Then the router will match /list and if there isn't a match, it will go to /:id

Comment: what you think I should do to make it work below that other route. Is ordering matter in express file.

Comment: It is working thanks. But what will you suggest is this correct way for using the route in express or I should follow another way.

Comment: This is fine. The order of routing matters in almost all routing frameworks. More specific routes (/listing) need to be called before less specific ones (/:id). Please mark the answer as accepted, if it explains :)